# Extracting json object and filling in user label

Tags: json

```
[{"id":1,"name":"ABC"},{"id":2,"name":"XYZ"}]
```

This is how the data is returned by the controller in json format

I want to store it in the following format:

```
var json = {
"users": [
             { "id": "1", "name": "ABC" },
             { "id": "2", "name": "XYZ" },
         ]
       }
```

Following is the code I have used but doesnt work.

```
  var json = 
  {
     "users": $.getJSON("@Url.Action("SearchCMSAdmins")")
  }              

 $("#DistributorCMSAdmin").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchWithName")", {
    theme: "facebook",                
    preventDuplicates: true,
    prePopulate:json.users
 });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getJson is asynchronous, so you need to use the success callback for getting the response and doing the operation. Try this INstead.

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("SearchCMSAdmins")",function(data){
    var json= {"users":data};
    $("#DistributorCMSAdmin").tokenInput("@Url.Action("SearchWithName")", {
       theme: "facebook",                
       preventDuplicates: true,
       prePopulate:json.users
    });
});
```